# Regular expression matching A, B, and AB

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I would like to create a regular expression that matches `A`, `B`, and `AB`, where `A` and `B` are quite complex regular expressions.

One solution is to use `(A|A?B)` or `(AB?|B)`, but then I have to repeat one of the expressions.

`A?B?` does not work, since this also matches the empty string.

Is it possible to create this regular expression without repeating neither `A` nor `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is not possible. You may use some workarounds though.

## If `A` and `B` start and end with word characters

In case the `A` and `B` are or start/end in *word type characters* (letters, digits or `_`, you may use

```
(?<!\w)A?(?:B)?(?!\w)(?<!\W(?!\w))(?<!^(?!\w))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MIgHFc/2)

- `(?<!\w)` - no word character allowed before
- `A?` - an optional `A`
- `(?:B)?` - an optional `B`
- `(?!\w)` - no word char is allowed right after (at this point, we may match empty strings between start of string and a non-word char, between a non-word and end of string or between two non-word chars, hence we add...)
- `(?<!\W(?!\w))` - no match allowed if right before is a non-word char that is not followed with a word char (this cancels empty matches between two non-word chars and a non-word char and end of string)
- `(?<!^(?!\w))` - no match allowed at the start of string if not followed with a word char.

## Avoid repeating part of the expression in an alternation based pattern

In PCRE, you may avoid repeating the same pattern part since you may recurse subpatterns with subroutine calls:

```
A(?<BGroup>B)?|(?&BGroup)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR7G7F/1).

The `(?<BGroup>B)` is a named capturing group whose pattern is repeated with the `(?&BGroup)` named subroutine call.

See [Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

Answer (score 2):

I would go for storing A and B into variables and create the pattern
(AB?|B) from A and B by concatenation. This has the advantage of enhancing readability as you can document the subpatterns A, and B.